# how to logon to different host machine and run some tool over there and get the data back to the original host using scripting

Tags: perl, automation, rsh

Problem statement:
consider the present scenario, i am running some commands/code on host-1, and i need to open a tool on host-2 where i may perform some operations on data obtained on host-1.

what i was doing till now was opening two different shells, one for host 1 and another for host 2, then i after running codes on host-1 would switch manually to the other shell prompt, where i would deal with the commands on tool. and would finally move back to the original shell.

An example would be executing a basic linux command on host-2 and capturing it response.
Ex:
do a **ls -l** on host-2 while we are on host-1 and get the results in some variable that could be kept for further processing.

Is there a way to automate this thing?? I mean a way in which i can logon to host-2 on the fly and execute those tool commands and get back to host-1 ?

I prefer writing a perl script for this.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @results = qx(ssh host-2 ls -l);

print @results;
```

Or are you looking for something more complicated?

Comment: No, what i was looking for is something like:
on Host-1:
....x...
....y....
....z....

then go to host 2 and execute some commands:
...123...
...342...
...r45...
... ls -l ...
etc... etc...

then again go back to host-1 and run some more commands

Comment: I have no idea what that means. You run my program on host-1 and it shows you the results of running `ls -l` on host-2. I thought that's what you asked for.

Comment: Please have a look at my updated comment to your answer...

I will try your code as well

Comment: I'm pretty sure that my example gives you enough of an example that you can build on it to do what you want. Use `qx(command)` to run stuff locally. Use `qx(ssh host command)` to run stuff remotely.

Comment: Pay attention to what @DaveCross has told you. Although, When I find my self running a lot of shell commands, I think of shell scripts. Especially in this case, because you didn't mention any post-processing of the resulting output.

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a look at Rex:

http://www.rexify.org/

But if Python is an option, you might also like Fabric:

http://www.fabfile.org/